# Parameters not saved on calling the same route in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a dropdown for search

```
 <select class="form-control" #Sel (change)="Select(Sel.value)">
              <option value="Permanent">Permanent</option>
              <option value="Contract">Contract</option>
 </select>

 <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="search">Search</button>
```

> `ts file`:

```
search()
{
   this.router.navigateByUrl('/', { skipLocationChange: true }).then(() =>
     this.router.navigate(['search']));
}
```

In this method it navigates to the same page and OnInit method is called

```
ngOnInit(): void {
   this.pagetype = this.route.snapshot.routeConfig.path;
   if(this.pagetype == 'search')
   {
       this.searchFilter();
   }
}
Select(data){
this.Filter.FilterType = data;
}
searchFilter() {
  FilterJson.FilterType = this.Filter.FilterType;
}
```

after calling `onInit` when i console `this.Filter.FilterType` this getting null value

Any solution to fix this issue, Thanks

Comment: you can add the filter type as a query param and then get it from there

Comment: @Barkha I don't want to use query param can i use local storage

Comment: yes you can use local storage as well but that won't work if you share url.
You can also use a service variable or if you are using ngRx then you can save it in that store and fetch from there

Comment: @Barkha will navigating to same page clear all the page variables?

Comment: yes it will reset component  variables 
service variables won't be reset if you decide to use those

Answer (score 0):

in `search` function, you navigated to `/` and after to `/search`, In this situation, Angular reconstructs the component and create a new instance. so if you want to keep the state of component on route changes, you can implement [`RouteReuseStrategy`](https://angular.io/api/router/RouteReuseStrategy) to cache the component instance and reuse it again.